# How style a repeatedType field form?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, symfony-forms

From symfony 5, I have a view containing a form (for create a new user). In this form, I add a RepeatedType field for the password.

All works fine.

Now I want add some style but I am having difficulties:

[image]

With the Symfony API, I found how add css class to the div '#user_password' (the black box in the image), I found how add css class to input (the green box in the image). But I can't find how add class to the div in the blue box in the image. I'm looking for a way to add the class 'col-6' to the 'blue div'

My code :

```
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'label' => false,
            'first_options'  => [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control trapezoid',
                    'placeholder' => 'Password'
                ]
            ],
            'second_options' => [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control trapezoid',
                    'placeholder' => 'Password²'
                ]
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'row',
            ],
            'row_attr' => [
                'class' => 'col-6', // has no effect
            ]
        ])
```

and the code in my twig file for the password fields:

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget( form.password) }}
</div>
{{ form_help(   form.password) }}
{{ form_errors( form.password) }}
```

Comment: First consider using bootstrap form theme (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html). Also can you show us twig file?

Comment: I add the twig code and I look at your link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '**row_attr**' **inside** **first_option** and **second_option**

```
'first_options'  => 
[
    'label' => false,
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control trapezoid',
        'placeholder' => 'Password'
    ],
    'row_attr' => [
        'class' => 'col-6', 
    ]
],
```